# Referencing a Cell in FIND in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is there way in VBA that instead of using "6/15/2020" as the reference, I use a specific cell as a reference. Lets say that I want that specific cell to be A1. I've been trying to do it in different ways and I just cant seem to get it to work.

```
Cells.Find(What:="6/15/2020", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

Comment: `What:=Range("A1").Value`.

Comment: Probably safe to change `xlFormulas2` to `xlFormulas`.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to change it up, I would store the cell value in a variable to make it easier to both review and change:

```
Dim ws as worksheet
Set ws = Thisworkbook.Worksheets(“YourSheetName”)

Val = ws.Range(“A1”).Value

Cells.Find(What:=Val, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```